# wire:submit.prevent='checkout' , is not invoking the function 'checkout' on button click

Tags: laravel-livewire

I am trying to invoke the function 'checkout' on button click. But when i click the button it just reload the page and do nothing. I am using livewire.

This is the blade file of the component.

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($products as $item )
        <div class="col mt-4">
            <image src='{{ $item->image }}' class="w-50 h-50"></image>
            <p>{{ $item->Product_name }}</p>
            <h4>${{ $item->price }}</h1>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <div>
        <form wire:submit.prevent="checkout">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Check out</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

This is the function that i want to call.

```
 public function checkout()
    {

        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SCERETE_KEY'));
        $products = Product::all();
        $lineItems = [];
        $total_price = 0;
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $total_price += $product->price;
            $lineItems = [
                'price_data' => [
                    'currency' => 'usd',
                    'product_data' => [
                        'name' => $product->Product_name,
                    ],
                    'unit_amount' => $product->price * 100,
                ],
                'quantity' => 1,
            ];
        }
        $checkout_session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
            'line_items' => $lineItems,
            'mode' => 'payment',
            'success_url' => route('checkout.success', [], absolute: true),
            'cancel_url' => route('checkout.cancel', [], absolute: true),
        ]);

        $order = new Order();
        $order->statuse = 'unpaind';
        $order->total_price = $total_price;
        $order->session_id = $checkout_session->id;
        $order->save();

        return redirect($checkout_session->url);
    }
```

When I click the submit button, it should redirect to the Stripe checkout page.

Comment: Does your Livewire component have a singular root `div`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a form tag. This should work just as good:

```
<button wire:click="checkout" class="btn btn-primary">Check out</button>
```

Comment: The problem was solved a long time ago. Thanks for your time.